# Using a variable in where clause

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-office

Using the following code:

```
Dim RCMSql As String
    RCMSql = "SELECT [Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].MaxOfDate_of_Transaction," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].FirstName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].LastName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Email_Address," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Address_Line_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_2," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Date_Sent," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemFlag " & _
    "FROM [Range Card Master Mailer] " & _
    "WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID) = '002366'))"
     RCMRs.Open RCMSql
```

This execute just fine, but if I change the where clause to use the value in a text box on the open form I get an error "No value give for one or more perameters"

```
"WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID) = Me!scanTxtBox))"
```

I have tried at least a dozen variations, but can't get it to works

Thanks

jpl

Comment: Could you please add the applicable tags for the DB you are using (Access, MySQL, MS SQL, etc.)?

Comment: Access 7, Office 7, SQL server

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
Dim RCMRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim RCMSql As String
RCMSql = "SELECT [Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].MaxOfDate_of_Transaction," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].FirstName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].LastName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Email_Address," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Address_Line_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_2," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Date_Sent," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemFlag " & _
    "FROM [Range Card Master Mailer] " & _
    "WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID) = '" & _
    Replace(Me!scanTxtBox, "'", "''") & "'))"
RCMRs.Open RCMSql
```

Comment: If not possible to work with parameterized queries, at least convert the TextBox content to an int, to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Thanks Ralph. Reading up on replace function.

Comment: It's likely that the value in scanTxtBox will contain leading zeros. So converting to integer will not work.  The value must be 6 characters long.

Comment: As far as I can tell my answer doesn't try to convert to int. So, is the provided solution working? If so, please close the question. If not, please let me know what's not working or where an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In your code define a local variable as string

If the first code you posted runs, `Master_ID` is defined as string, so, define a local variable with

```
Dim localScanTxtBox as string
```

and set it with (if in your scanTxtBox you have a 6-char string):

```
localScanTxtBox = Me!scanTxtBox
```

or,  convert it to a 6-digit string with:

```
localScanTxtBox = format$(Me!scanTxtBox,"000000")
```

Then write your `where statement` as:

```
WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID) = '" & localscanTxtBox & "'))
```

Hope this helps